# Align BandsinTown widget & picture

Tags: html, css

I am looking to align a bandsintown widget and a picture of my band. The widget & picture should resize based on what the browser size is. I have researched and tried different ones, but am unable to get it to work.

Here is the bandsintown widget code:

```html
 <div id="wrap" class="section" id="news">
                <script src="https://widget.bandsintown.com/main.min.js"></script>
                <a class="bit-widget-initializer" data-artist-name="Band Name" data-display-past-dates="true" data-widget-width="50%" data-font='Frente H1'></a>
               <img src="/images/pic.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is `float` both the `.bit-widget-container` (generated by the script) and your desired image to the `left`:

```css
.bit-widget-container, #news > img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="section wrap" id="news">
  <script src="https://widget.bandsintown.com/main.min.js"></script>
  <a class="bit-widget-initializer" data-artist-name="Band Name" data-display-past-dates="true" data-widget-width="50%" data-font='Frente H1'></a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200">
</div>
```

Keep in mind that your snippet has duplicate IDs (`wrap` and `news`), which is **invalid markup**. As such, I've changed your `wrap` ID to a **class** in the above snippet.

You also used a relative link to an image, which I've replaced with a placeholder so that you can see the image aligns correctly.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response? What about if I want both to resize relative to the screen size, and remain side by side, is that possible?

Comment: That's what `float: left` does; it makes sure the two elements stay next to each other. If you give both elements `width: 50%` (or any total that equals 100%), they will automatically scale when the screen resizes. Having said that, you may wish to drop them below one another from mobiles. That would require media queries, and would likely benefit from a framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation :)